# Compiler cannot copy NuGet package DLL from WPF library to WPF program

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, webview2, libvlcsharp

I have a very simple setup with two WPF projects in Visual Studio 2022: a WPF application and a WPF library.

Both projects are extremely simple - they contain only a simple empty WPF Window each and when the program starts it opens both. That works.

Then I add a reference to WebView2 in the library and include a WebView2 browser in the library window. This also works fine.

Now I also want to include a video feed and add LibVLCSharp.WPF to the library. Then I include a video player in the library window. This also works fine - I can show video and web side by side.

In my real application I need to reference .NET target framework "net6.0-windows10.0.18362.0" instead of "net6.0-windows". So I change that in both project files.

At this point I get the following error:

```
NETSDK1082: There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win10-arm'.
```

It seems to be caused by VLC that does not work on WIN10-ARM.

Now I reduce the targets to Windows only by adding this to the project files:

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;win10-x86;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

... and now the compiler fails in a way I cannot fix:

```
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5198,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\Work\WpfApp1\WpfLibrary1\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.18362.0\WpfLibrary1\runtimes\win-x64\native\WebView2Loader.dll" because it was not found.
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5198,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\Work\WpfApp1\WpfLibrary1\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.18362.0\WpfLibrary1\runtimes\win-arm64\native\WebView2Loader.dll" because it was not found.
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5198,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\Work\WpfApp1\WpfLibrary1\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.18362.0\WpfLibrary1\runtimes\win-x86\native\WebView2Loader.dll" because it was not found.
```

For some reason it cannot copy WebView2Loader.dll from the library project to the main project.

Looking closer, it seems to copy from the wrong source. It looks for:

```
C:\Work\WpfApp1\WpfLibrary1\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.18362.0\WpfLibrary1\runtimes\win-x64\native\WebView2Loader.dll
```

But the file is located in:

```
C:\Work\WpfApp1\WpfLibrary1\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.18362.0\runtimes\win-x64\native\WebView2Loader.dll
```

For some odd reason the compiler tries to copy from "...\WpfLibrary1\runtimes" when it should be "...\runtimes" - it is only that additional "WpfLibrary1" that results in the error.

Question: Can anyone tell my why this happens - and maybe what I need to do to fix it?

Edits:

- The WebView2 files are actually copied to the main application directory by some other step of the compilation process.

**Sources**

WpfLibrary1.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.18362.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;win10-x86;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="LibVLCSharp.WPF" Version="3.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.WebView2" Version="1.0.2151.40" />    
  </ItemGroup>
  
</Project>
```

WpfApp1.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.18362.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;win10-x86;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\WpfLibrary1\WpfLibrary1.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```